# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The ViewData item that has the key 'X is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I got this error when I want to Create my Contact. Need help I would be thankful.
My database SQL database table is connected via entity framework.

Home Controller / Create Action

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()

    {
        List<Country> CountryList = db.Countries.ToList();
        ViewBag.CountryList = new SelectList(CountryList, "CountryId", "CountryName");

        return View();

    }






    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]





 public ActionResult Create(CountryStateContactViewModel csvm)


    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)

        {

            return View(csvm);

        }
       
        Contact model = new Contact()
        {
            CountryId = csvm.CountryId,
            StateId = csvm.StateId,
            ContactId = csvm.ContactId,
            ImeOsobe = csvm.ImeOsobe
            ...and all other fields

            
        };
        db.Contacts.Add(model);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException db)
        {
            Exception raise = db;
            foreach (var validationErrors in db.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);

                    raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                }
            }
            throw raise;

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Now here is ViewModel

```
public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Naziv županije")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Naziv općine")]
    public string StateName { get; set; }


    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    ....and all other fields
```

And finally here is "Create" view.

```
@model AkvizicijeApp_4_7.Models.CountryStateContactViewModel




 @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  }

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" 
 })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, ViewBag.CountryList as SelectList, "--Select 
 Country--", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" 
 })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, new SelectList(" "), "--Select State--", new { 
 @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
 </div>


 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>CountryStateContactViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    


    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label 
 col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = 
 "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" 
  })
            </div>
        </div>
```

And after that is all other fields and js for parent/child dropdown list.

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
 }
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#CountryId").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home/GetStateList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#StateId").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.StateId + "'>" + row.StateName + " 
 </option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
 </script>
```

Please help me solve my problem. <3

Comment: You are getting error on `CountryId` or `StateId` ?

Comment: CountryId is problem for now

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue

Comment: Why? You cannot see what is wrong or?

Comment: I mean, I didn't get the error on the `GET` request for `CountryId` `dropdown`, it displayed fine.